# htaccess rewrites url on the address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a blog (not a Wordpress one, just a very simple html/css blog) on a hosting provider.
I recently moved my blog from the root folder to an internal folder `/www/dist`.

Since the blog has many referral links on the web, I'd want the url to my blog posts stay the same, as if I never moved the blog to that folder.

Let's take as an example one of my posts: "forza 4 in c".

Before moving the blog, here it was the url to access the blog post:
https://www.gianlucaghettini.net/forza-4-in-c

Right now, to access the same blog post, I have to go to:
https://www.gianlucaghettini.net/www/dist/forza-4-in-c

I want to keep the url the same, so:
https://www.gianlucaghettini.net/forza-4-in-c

To achieve that, that's how I configured the htaccess file on the root. Basically I'm telling apache to redirect all the requests to /www/dist.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gianlucaghettini\.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gianlucaghettini\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/dist/
RewriteRule (.*) /www/dist/$1 [L]
```

I hoped that wouldn't change the address bar but that's not the case, I can see the address bar with the extra `/www/dist` part on the url.

Now, shouldn't the RewriteRule suppose to keep the url the same? Why I see such behavior?

**UPDATE**

I'm being told by the hosting team that the url update happens on my pc only. I tried to open the link from different clients, even from a different ip address but I still see the url being updated.

**UPDATE no.2**

It looks like everything works fine if I add a final slash `/` to all the links. In this case the url in the address bar is not changed.

Comment: Could you please do let me know if you have any other htaccess also in near by folders etc? OR do you have more rules also in your this current htaccess file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 There's only that htaccess file. It's on the root folder.

Comment: And it has only these rules none other, just want to make sure we are having all info here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 only these rules, no more

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.